# What are the more important columns to include in NONCLUSTERED INDEX - from Group by or Where?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, group-by, nonclustered-index, where

I am thinking about adding a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` to a table in SQL Server 2016. I found that most queries refers to `WHERE` clause like:

```
WHERE varcharColumn <> '' 
and varcharColumn2 = '2' 
and varcharColumn3 in ('A','B')
```

but also most of queries has `GROUP BY` statement like:

`GROUP BY varcharColumn4, varcharColumn5, varcharColumn6`

so we are grouping for different columns than in `WHERE` clause.

What is a good approach for adding `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` for this table ?

Answer (score 2):

Typically the WHERE clause is processed before the GROUP BY, so think about it in terms of which will have the most effect. If you've got 1,000,000 rows in your table and your WHERE clause will filter most of them out, then index for the WHERE clause (first), and specifically on the columns that will be most effective at filtering out more rows. If the WHERE clause won't filter much out then the sorting might be more important so indexing for the GROUP BY might make the most sense.

Obviously the best is to test against different representative workloads.

I'd recommend blogs & training from [Brent](https://www.brentozar.com/) on query tuning & thinking like SQL Server for good ways to think about these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 1):

**Grouping is best done with a sorted input, so we really want to maintain ordered reading from the index.** This means that inequality columns cannot be used, as this will mess up the ordering. Equality columns should still come first.

Breaking down your current query, we can try and estimate which columns would be most useful:

```sql
WHERE varcharColumn <> ''
-- prob not useful as a key column because it's an inequality
and varcharColumn2 = '2'
-- should be leading column as it's equality
and varcharColumn3 in ('A','B')
-- IN is an OR, so not that useful
GROUP BY varcharColumn4, varcharColumn5, varcharColumn6
-- grouping is best when sorted, so these should be next
```

**This means the best index is likely to be**

```
(varcharColumn2, varcharColumn4, varcharColumn5, varcharColumn6)
  INCLUDE (varcharColumn, varcharColumn3)
```

---

**Another possible option is**

```
(varcharColumn2, varcharColumn3, varcharColumn4, varcharColumn5, varcharColumn6)
  INCLUDE (varcharColumn)
```

However, this is only likely to work if the compiler picks an index-union strategy, which it might not do.

You can force an index-union using something like the following code

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM
(
    SELECT varcharColumn2, varcharColumn3, varcharColumn4, varcharColumn5, varcharColumn6, varcharColumn
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE varcharColumn <> '' 
      and varcharColumn2 = '2' 
      and varcharColumn3 = 'A'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT varcharColumn2, varcharColumn3, varcharColumn4, varcharColumn5, varcharColumn6, varcharColumn
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE varcharColumn <> '' 
      and varcharColumn2 = '2' 
      and varcharColumn3 = 'B'
) t
GROUP BY varcharColumn4, varcharColumn5, varcharColumn6
```

---

**If the final resultset is likely to be small,** and the inequality column is doing most of the filtering, it may be worth placing it as a key column. This means a sort or hash will be required to group, but on a small set it's not a big deal.

```
(varcharColumn2, varcharColumn)
  INCLUDE (varcharColumn4, varcharColumn5, varcharColumn6, varcharColumn3)
```

Comment: worth noting that if you have a group by you probably have at least you aggregate function and the columns that you are aggregating should be added to the include of your new index